# Android: My thread leaves the black screen of mobile infinitely

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a problem with an application with a manager thread to perform the catch data and store them in memory for use, but it turns out that when the thread is released ( when creating the main activity) black screen remains infinitely powerless Do nothing. The database is fine, because the use without the thread and was perfectly.

My Thead:

```
public class HiloBD extends Activity implements Runnable{

    ManejoBD baseDatos;
    MainActivity main;
    boolean salir=false;

    HiloBD(MainActivity main){
        this.main=main;
        baseDatos=new ManejoBD(main);
    }

    public void run(){

        main.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (!salir) {
                    Toast.makeText(main, "Vamos a guardar la BD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    baseDatos.volcarBDArrays();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(600000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    baseDatos.guardarDatosCursos();
                    baseDatos.guardarDatosAlumnos();
                    Toast.makeText(main, "BASE DE DATOS ACTUALIZADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }
    public void setSalir(boolean sal){
        salir = sal;
    }
```

I call the thread like this (In the Main):

```
HiloBD hilo=new HiloBD(this);
    Thread hiloEjecutar=new Thread(hilo);
    hiloEjecutar.start();
```

Thx.

Comment: `My thread leaves the black screen of mobile infinitely` because calling `Thread.sleep(600000);` on UI Thread. if possible then try it using `handler.postdelayed`

Comment: I used the handler.postDelayed but the result is the same , I think the problem is in the loop, because if you take off while the application runs (one time makes the operation ) .
Just utilzo a control variable that changes when you exit or the app closes, there should be no problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Handler creates thread from main thread which causes the black screen, so any task which will take considerable amount of time should be used with `ScheduledExecutorService` 
just create it's object like so.

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

and use it like.

```
scheduler.schedule(runnable, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

runnable is the Runnable, 0 is the delay and TimeUnit is the unit of the delay

Here is the Android doc for it
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService